# Rename layer after gdal:rasterize

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, qgis-processing

I rasterized a layer using `gdal:rasterize` like this:

```py
raster = processing.run(
    "gdal:rasterize",
    {...},
    is_child_algorithm=True,
    context=context,
    feedback=feedback
)
```

But `gdal:rasterize` always seems to name its result layer `Rasterize`, which is too generic for my taste. And AFAIK it's not possible to provide a resulting output layer name as input. So I figured, let's rename it to something more sensible after rasterizing.

I tried doing the following

```
layer = QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(raster['OUTPUT'], context)
layer.setName('New Name')
layer.setOpacity(0.5)
```

Which all runs fine and I can see the opacity being set as well. But not the name. Also I noticed that `OGR` reports a warning when I call `mapLayerFromString`

```
WARNING Cannot open .../AppData/Local/Temp/processing_FxniEY/4c9c57d...643569/OUTPUT.tif ().()
```

Yet `mapLayerFromString` does return a valid layer and I'm able to change its opacity. So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface` class.

Here is a simple example for renaming an output raster layer after running gdal:rasterize and changing the opacity (Name will only be changed if output is temporary layer. If user saves output to a file, the filename will be used):

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                        QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                        QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer,
                        QgsProcessingParameterField,
                        QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination,
                        QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface,
                        QgsRasterLayer)
import processing
                       
class ExAlgo(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    FIELDS = 'FIELDS'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
    def name(self):
        return "exalgo"
     
    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("exalgo", text)
         
    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr("Example script")
 
    def group(self):
        return self.tr("Examples")
 
    def groupId(self):
        return "examples"
 
    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example script which renames an output raster")
 
    def helpUrl(self):
        return "https://qgis.org"
         
    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()
   
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(self.INPUT,
            'Input vector',
            defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterField(self.FIELDS,
            'fields to select',
            allowMultiple=False,
            type = QgsProcessingParameterField.Numeric,
            defaultToAllFields=True,
            parentLayerParameterName=self.INPUT))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination(self.OUTPUT,
            'Output raster',
            createByDefault=True,
            defaultValue=None))
 
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        results = {}
        outputs = {}
        
        vector = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
        field = self.parameterAsFields(parameters, self.FIELDS, context)[0]
        
        params = {
                'BURN': 0,
                'DATA_TYPE': 5,
                'EXTENT': vector.extent(),
                'EXTRA': '',
                'FIELD': field,
                'INIT': None,
                'INPUT': parameters[self.INPUT],
                'INVERT': False,
                'NODATA': 0,
                'OPTIONS': '',
                'UNITS': 0,
                'HEIGHT':250,
                'WIDTH': 500,
                'OUTPUT': parameters[self.OUTPUT]
            }
            
        outputs['rasterized'] = processing.run('gdal:rasterize', params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['OUTPUT'] = outputs['rasterized']['OUTPUT']
        
        if context.willLoadLayerOnCompletion(results['OUTPUT']):
            context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(results['OUTPUT']).setPostProcessor(MyLayerPostProcessor.create())
 
        return results
        
class MyLayerPostProcessor(QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface):

    instance = None

    def postProcessLayer(self, layer, context, feedback):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        if not isinstance(layer, QgsRasterLayer):
            return
        if layer.name() == 'Rasterized':
            layer.setName('Better_name')
        layer.setOpacity(0.5)

    # Hack to work around sip bug!
    @staticmethod
    def create() -> 'MyLayerPostProcessor':
        MyLayerPostProcessor.instance = MyLayerPostProcessor()
        return MyLayerPostProcessor.instance
```

Acknowledgements: The basis of the code for the `MyLayerPostProcessor` subclass I copied from an example in a github gist of Nyall Dawson's which has since been deleted (so I can't provide a link to it) but I feel I should give the due credit.

Some of the script 'boiler plate' is based on a template from Anita Graser's Blog [here](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/).

**Edit:**

I have been playing around with this a bit. This approach also seems to work (However this is only useful if you want to simply modify the output memory layer name). If you want to modify styling etc. the layer post processor would still be the preferred method. I include this here just for interest.

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    
    ...
    # Rest of code same as full example above
    ...
        
    outputs['rasterized'] = processing.run('gdal:rasterize', params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['OUTPUT'] = outputs['rasterized']['OUTPUT']
    
    if context.willLoadLayerOnCompletion(results['OUTPUT']):
        details = context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(results['OUTPUT'])
        l = QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(results['OUTPUT'], context, typeHint=details.layerTypeHint)
        if l.name() == 'OUTPUT':
            details.name = 'Better_Name'
            details.forceName = True

    return results
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used this answer to derive my own post-processor class. I am calling the create method on multiple layers but only the last layer is getting post-processed. Not sure what is wrong since we are creating a new instance. Here is my code. https://github.com/Dewberry/QNSPECT/blob/531eeccea03c27b87778cddeea3ba2b94fc7f9bc/algorithms/run_analysis/run_pollution_analysis.py#L84

Comment: Thanks. I posted a separate question here as well, lets's see if anyone can answer. If not, I will probably file a bug with QGIS.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423650/qgsprocessinglayerpostprocessorinterface-only-processing-the-last-layer

Comment: I provided the answer to my question, you may want to see it. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423650/qgsprocessinglayerpostprocessorinterface-only-processing-the-last-layer

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setName()` on the layer also does not work for me. What works is changing the name in the layer details:

```
layer_details = context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(raster['OUTPUT'])
layer_details.name = "New Name"
```