# QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface only processing the last layer

Tags: pyqgis, post-processing

I have a `QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface` class as shown below.

```py
class LayerPostProcessor(QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface):
    instance = None
    name = ""
    color1 = tuple()
    color2 = tuple()

    def postProcessLayer(self, layer, context, feedback):
        feedback.pushInfo("here")
        if layer.isValid():
            layer.setName(self.name)

            prov = layer.dataProvider()
            stats = prov.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All, layer.extent(), 0)
            min = stats.minimumValue
            max = stats.maximumValue
            renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(layer.dataProvider(), 1)
            color_ramp = QgsGradientColorRamp(
                QColor(*self.color1), QColor(*self.color2)
            )
            renderer.setClassificationMin(min)
            renderer.setClassificationMax(max)
            renderer.createShader(color_ramp)
            layer.setRenderer(renderer)

    # Hack to work around sip bug!
    @staticmethod
    def create(name, color1, color2) -> "LayerPostProcessor":
        LayerPostProcessor.instance = LayerPostProcessor()
        LayerPostProcessor.name = name
        LayerPostProcessor.color1 = color1
        LayerPostProcessor.color2 = color2
        return LayerPostProcessor.instance
```

In my main code, I loop over multiple layers and want to style them using the above class, but when I do that only the last layer is styled. I tried deepcopy and subclass, nothing worked. Can't seem to figure out what is going on.

I changed the class and tried initiating it in a regular way using the **init** method. That didn't work at all, even the last layer didn't get post-processed.

```py
    for display_name, layer in layers.items():
        layer_details = context.LayerDetails(
            display_name, context.project(), display_name
        )
        context.addLayerToLoadOnCompletion(
            layer,
            layer_details,
        )
        if context.willLoadLayerOnCompletion(layer):
            context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(layer).setPostProcessor(
                LayerPostProcessor.create(display_name, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255))
            )
```

Comment: Have you tried applying the style at the end of the `processAlgorithm` method (if you are running this within a Processing Algorithm)? You can style multiple outputs without the need for a PostProcessor